# SQL - Split data from same column to multiple column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as below:

```
Column1:
1
10
20
30
2
40
50
60
3
70
80
90
```

Output should be:

```
Column1 Column2:
10 1
20 1
30 1
40 2
50 2
60 2
70 3
80 3
90 3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split one column to multiple columns but data will vary SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588800/split-one-column-to-multiple-columns-but-data-will-vary-sql)

Comment: Do you have any other columns that denote the order of your data, and what should be in Column1 and what in Column2? If not, what you ask is impossible.

Comment: How do you know whether `2` comes before `40` or before a different row? Remember that tables are unordered sets

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1):

your data

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   Column1 INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  
);
INSERT INTO mytable(Column1) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO mytable(Column1) VALUES (10);
INSERT INTO mytable(Column1) VALUES (20);
INSERT INTO mytable(Column1) VALUES (30);
INSERT INTO mytable(Column1) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO mytable(Column1) VALUES (40);
INSERT INTO mytable(Column1) VALUES (50);
INSERT INTO mytable(Column1) VALUES (60);
INSERT INTO mytable(Column1) VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO mytable(Column1) VALUES (70);
INSERT INTO mytable(Column1) VALUES (80);
INSERT INTO mytable(Column1) VALUES (90);
```

use `NTILE` in sql server it acts as Tile and hence solve your issue.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT column1,
               Ntile (3)
                 OVER (
                   ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) ) Column2
        FROM   mytable) m
WHERE  column1 <> column2
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=da0f35486b6c86d5ff74f042a5c95f63)

Comment: You didn't just attempt to answer this unclear question, but also answered with the best possible way.

Comment: `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` Logical nonsense. This only **appears** to provide a consistent result.

Comment: Using Order by (select  null)  is intend to create natural numbers 1 2 3 4